# Trying to break out of scanner

Tags: java

I have a scanner input which only takes an integer. If I were to type in a string, it would reject and ask the user to type until it sees a proper integer. I have a try/catch block for it, however even after the user enters an integer for it, it still continues to prompt the user to enter another integer.  How can I code this in such a way that once the first integer is read it will stop the program completely and return the result?

This is my current code now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int key1 = 0;


    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter integer number only");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();
        int b =0;   

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "readfromfile.txt"))) {
            b = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(b == (int)b){
                System.out.println("Correct Integer entered!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            System.out.println("Input is not a number, please enter number!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider the condition you have provided for the while loop, how that value is never changed, nor can it be. What you have is an `infinite loop`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping `while (true)`, so your loop will never end as it is written.

You can add a `break` statement after you've gotten the number you like to terminate the loop:

```
    if(b == (int)b){
        System.out.println("Correct Integer entered!");
        break;
    }
```

You can read more about `break` and other branching statements in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).  These are fairly fundamental parts of Java, so you should get familiar with them.

An alternate method is to use a variable to keep track of whether or not you've found a number.

Instead of looping `while (true)`, you can set the initial state of your variable to `true`, and flip it once you've found a number you like:

```
    boolean stillLooking = true;
    while (stillLooking) {
        ...
        if(b == (int)b){
            System.out.println("Correct Integer entered!");
            stillLooking = false;
        }
        ...
    }
```

One further note is that `Integer.parseInt(input)` is guaranteed to either return an `int`, or throw a `NumberFormatException`.  Trying to check for `int`-ness is redundant with the exception handling you've already written, so you can just do this:

```
    b = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // if input cannot be parsed to an int, this line will not be reached
    System.out.println("Correct Integer entered!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping with `while (true)`, you should put a guard like :

```
boolean correctAnswer = false;
while (!correctAnswer) {
   // read input from user
   // ...
   if (<input is what expected>) {
      correctAnswer = true;
   }
}
```

Note :

```
if(b == (int)b){
    System.out.println("Correct Integer entered!");
}
```

Will always print `Correct...`, because `b` is always equals to `(int)b` since `b` is declared as an `int`. I guess you want to compare with a value read in the file you are not yet using.